# How to configure LLVM MCJIT for armhf?

Tags: arm, llvm, jit, mcjit

I'm trying to build simple application with JIT based on LLVM 3.8 for Raspberry PI 2. I built LLVM for ARM and my application successfully jitted the code, but it seams that LLVM generates code for softfp instead of hardfp.

How can I configure LLVM to generate code for hardfp?

LLVM was configured with `arm-linux-gnueabihf` target. From the code I specified `setArch` as `arm` and `setMCU` as `cortex-a7`.

Comment: I have absolutely zero knowledge of MCJIT, but digging through the docs looking for parallels to the command-line options, I see `::createJIT` takes a `TargetMachine`, which takes a `TargetOptions`, which [has a `::FloatABIType`](http://www.llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1TargetOptions.html#a44277c39cd6496cc63dace4b1eb36bb7) - is that at all relevant?

Comment: @Notlikethat it should, but setting `FloatABI::Hard` via `setTargetOptions` doesn't help.